# How to convert vector to string in java?

Tags: java, vector

I have a `vector` and it `contains` the `value 5`. When i do `System.out.Println(vectorVariable)`, the value outputted is `[5]`. I want to convert the vectorVariable to string (without the []). I have tried `vectorVariable.toString()`, which converts it to a string but it still retains the []. So i guess i what i really want is the first element to be returned as a string. How is this possible?

I want to store the value of the vector inside a string without the [].

Comment: If you have several values in your vector and you want to print theses values without [ or in a fancy way, you have to override the toString() method.

Comment: I have several values but i only need the first. When i retrieve the first i always get the [] surrounding the body of the value

Comment: Ok, it was just in case you wanted to print more specific values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `System.out.println(vector.get(0))`. You are trying to print the entire vector, whereas this will only print the selected index, in this case 0.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to get the value from the vector, rather than print the vector itself.

```
  System.out.println(vectorVariable.get(0));
```

This gets the first value and prints it. Of course you need to verify that the vector contains a value before you do this.

Comment: There goes my question of the day.. ugh u guys are insanely quick.

Comment: For some reason the value is still returned as [5] =/

Comment: Just tested and i get a returning value with the brackets []. Not sure why i cant just select the value ..

Comment: Post a bit more code so we can see what you are doing. Maybe something else is happening.

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
for (String string : vectorVariable) {
    System.out.println(string);
}
```