# Convert char vector into a String in Java

Tags: java, string, vector, char

I want to convert my char vector into a String in Java. The only method I know is first convert the vector into a char array and then convert the char array into a String. But I need to find a way to convert char Vector directly to a String.

Comment: Please don't use `Vector`; use `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: StringBuilder and iterate over the vector?

Comment: How about `Vector`'s [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#toString()) method?

Comment: Please give an example. Will PM77-1's solution suffice or do you want to convert it to a String as a readable word without commas between letters?

Comment: Why are you storing char in a Vector? Keep in mind that they are being wrapped to (and unwrapped from) Character when you try to add (and get)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [convert vector to string in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895186/how-to-convert-vector-to-string-in-java). There is no direct conversion method. Using the toString() method would print the characters enclosed by [](just like an array). Iterate over the characters in the vector and either print them directly or add them to a stringbuilder to create the string

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods, none are direct. Even if the API exposes a single method, the actual time complexities for that way as opposed to any other will be very similar.

You can iterate through the Vector and append each Character to a String

```
Vector<Character> charList = yourCharVector;

String vectorAsConcatenatedString = "";
for (Character c : charList)
    vectorAsConcatenatedString += c;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 7, simply invoking `Vector#toString()` will work. Quoted from [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html):

> Returns a string representation of this Vector, containing the String representation of each element.

In Java 6, I don't think `toString()` does this. I would create a `Stringbuilder` object of the required size `Stringbuilder sb = new Stringbuilder(v.size());` and then iterate over the vector to append one character at a time. Finally, of course, returning `sb.toString()`.